# Значение переменной

Tags: jquery

Доброго времени суток!

Есть код:

```
var col;

$('#exampleMenu>li>a').click(function () {
    col = $(this).parent("li").attr("class");
    col += 'm';
})

if (col != undefined) {
    $('#maincolumn').addClass('m1m');
}
```

Подскажите, почему класс не добавляется?

Comment: .    
    $('#exampleMenu>li>a').click(function(){
      $(this).parent("li").attr("class"); col+='m';
      $('#maincolumn').addClass('m1m');
    })

Comment: мне надо добавить класс после события click()

Comment: А код представленный выше и делает это. В чем проблема?

Comment: по событию click() у меня происходит переход по ссылке, мне нужно, чтобы страница загрузилась и добавился класс.

Comment: @woland обновил ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что `col` выполняется не после клика. Следовательно, он `undefined`. Хотите добавлять класс - запихните условие в обработчик `onclick`.

Чтобы отменить выполнение дефолтного поведения элемента, можно использовать в обработчике `return false`.

Comment: или в конце клика сделайте return col+='m'

Comment: не работает

Comment: если написать return false просто выводит alert 1